# How to add an image with alt tag but without caption in Pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

As described in the [manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images), in Pandoc’s Markdown images are added by

```
![This is the caption](/url/of/image.png)
```

The string `This is the caption` is added as a caption to the image as well as in the alt tag of the image.

I need the alt tags of the images, but want to avoid the captions for some of the images in an epub document. Is there an easy way to accomplish this, e.g. by css?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pandoc treats an image that is the only content of a paragraph as a figure and prints the alt text as a caption. You can append an escaped linebreak to suppress this behaviour:

```
![This is the caption](/url/of/image.png) \
```

Comment: As explained here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images